# Google Sheets ImportXML on Coinmarketcap.com

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a google sheet that I use to track crypto positions and I'm using ImportXML to grab the current price of the coin off of coinmarketcap.com. All of them work with the same set of parameters:

1. URL https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies//
2. Full XPath: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span

Formula:
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/the-sandbox/", "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span", "en US")

This works for every coin I've tried EXCEPT SAND (https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/the-sandbox/) and I've no clue why. I have tried pretty much every combination of the path I can think of.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am totally stuck on this one.

Comment: Probably be good to share an example or explain what "doesn't work" means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/the-sandbox/"; 
 "//div[@class='priceValue ']")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want have pure number without $ try this:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/";  "//div[@class='priceValue ']") ;"$";"");",";"");".";","))
```